# Twitter Share Link Will Only Show First Word Of Topic Title

Tags: twitter, share

hi guys basically I have something called $content[topic] which in php would show the topic which could be something like "Platformers What Are They"

but when a user would click on my share button for twitter it will only show "PLATFORMERS [The LINK]" and not the whole title that I wanted showing, how do I correct this?

here is the code for the share button I am using

```
<a href=https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.sentuamessage.com/blog.php?who=$content[id]&text=$content[topic]&hashtags=blogs,SentUAMessage target=new>Image Here</a>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Are you URL encoding the variables?

Comment: awh I understand what you mean and the answer is no, how would I do that, how would I change it so $content[topic] adds all the %20 to distinguish the spaces?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: im using php so would it be like replacing $content[topic] in the address to something like $link then defining $link = sometypeofcoding($content[topic]); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [URLencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) all your variables.

In your case, do something like....

```
$URL = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?"
    + "url=" + urlencode("http://www.sentuamessage.com/blog.php?")
    + "&who=" + urlencode($content[id])
    + "&text=" + urlencode($content[topic])
    + "&hashtags=" + urlencode("blogs,SentUAMessage");
```

Basically, make sure everything is properly encoded.

Comment: really appreciate that, since you mentioned URL ENCODING I did some google searching but it took me around converting character sets from current to ASCII and I was trying to figure around that but this urlencode and breaking everything apart to ensure it is properly encoded helps a lot and teaches me to become a lot neater whilst covering everything. Thank you